# Paho MQTT Callbacks Not Triggering

Tags: python, paho

I am using Paho to connect to my MQTT brooker, however, the callbacks are not working as expected. I have followed the documentation and can't comprehend why the functions are going unnoticed.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import mqttUtils as utils

# Subscribe To Topic


def subscribeToTopic(client, topic):
    try:
        result = client.subscribe(topic, 2)
        if result[0] == 0:
            utils.logging.info("Successfuly Subscribed To Topic")
            return 1
    except:
        utils.logging.info("Failed Subscribe Attempt")
        return 0


def on_subscribe(client, userdata, mid, granted_qos):  # subscribe to mqtt broker
    print("Subscribed", userdata)



host = "x"
client = mqtt.Client()
client.connect(host, port=1883, keepalive=60, bind_address="")
# result = utils.connectToMqtt(client,utils.host)
client.on_subscribe = on_subscribe
subscribeResult = subscribeToTopic(client, "test")
```

Here is my code, I am declaring the on_subscribe method before subscribing, yet the script refuses to work. Does anyone know why the callbacks are not being fired?

Comment: do you get any error message ? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: There is no error message, only the logs are outputted. The output is 'Successfully subscribed to topic' Therefore, the output for the result variable is (0,1)

Answer (score 0):

Program has to run all time and receives messages from server and when it gets confirmation from server then it will run `on_subscribe`.

You can use ie.

```
client.loop_forever()
```

to run it all time

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def on_subscribe(client, userdata, mid, granted_qos):
    print("Subscribed", client, userdata, mid, granted_qos)

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    #print('on_message:', client, userdata, message)
    #print(dir(message))
    print('on_message:', message.payload.decode())

host = "mqtt.eclipse.org"

client = mqtt.Client()
client.connect(host, port=1883, keepalive=60, bind_address="")
client.on_message = on_message
client.on_subscribe = on_subscribe
client.subscribe('temp', 1)

client.loop_forever()
```

---

Doc: [paho-mqtt](https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/)